# Find the closure of a convex set in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I don't really know how to approach the following exercise.

Consider in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ the functions

$$
f_r(x):=
\begin{cases}
0 &&0\le x \le r,\\
\frac{x-r}{1-r} &&r < x \le 1,\\
\end{cases}
$$
with $r \in [0,1]$. Prove that the closure of the convex hull of $\{f_r \ | \ r \in [0,1] \}$ in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is the set of the convex functions, increasing  such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, show that the described set (convex functions such that...) is a closed convex subset of the space.

Secondly, show that all piecewise linear functions with the described properties are in the convex hull of $\{f_r\mid r\}$ (e.g. by induction with respect to the number of pieces), and then show that the piecewise linear functions are dense.